# If cell matches a certain value in a column, insert data in an adjacent column

Tags: excel, vba

So I have two forms in Sheet `EmployeeForm` (EmployeeForm1 & EmployeeForm2) and an Excel Table `TableEmployee` in Sheet `EmployeeData` that looks like this:
[image]

The data in the table comes from the submission from these two forms, but so far I've only succeeded in inputting the first half of the table.

The data in `Employee Form 2` is submitted only and only after the `Employee Form 1` is submitted (can be days, even weeks later).

Now what I want to achieve is to have a working VBA code that can match the `Employee ID` in cell D13 with `Employee ID` in column H correctly, and record the data in D14:D17 to its proper place.

So in this example above, since the `Employee ID` is 145, once I click the submit button in Form 2, the data in D14:D17 should be stored in L7:O7.

This is my code so far:

```
Sub Submit_Form1()

   Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet

   Set ws = Worksheets("EmployeeData")

   LastRow = ws.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

   ws.Range("H" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("EmployeeForm").Range("D5").Value   'Employee ID
   ws.Range("I" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("EmployeeForm").Range("D6").Value   'Employee Name
   ws.Range("J" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("EmployeeForm").Range("D7").Value  'Place of Birth
   ws.Range("K" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("EmployeeForm").Range("D8").Value  'Working Experience


 End Sub
```

And for Form 2

```
Sub Submit_Form2()

    Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Dim H As String

   Set ws = Worksheets("EmployeeData")
    employeeid = Sheets("EmployeeForm").Range("D13").Value

    If Cells(H) = employeeid Then

     ws.Range("L" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("EmployeeForm").Range("D14").Value   'Education
     ws.Range("M" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("EmployeeForm").Range("D15").Value   'Last Company
    ws.Range("N" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("EmployeeForm").Range("D16").Value  'Join Date
    ws.Range("O" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("EmployeeForm").Range("D17").Value  'Position

 End Sub
```

Of course, the second macro doesnt work, but can anybody please enlighten me as how to do this the right way? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
Sub Submit_Form2()

Dim ws As Worksheet, v As Variant

Set ws = Worksheets("EmployeeData")
employeeid = Sheets("EmployeeForm").Range("D13").Value

v = Application.Match(employeeid, ws.Range("H:H"), 0)

If IsNumeric(v) Then
    ws.Range("L" & v).Value = Worksheets("EmployeeForm").Range("D14").Value   'Education
    ws.Range("M" & v).Value = Worksheets("EmployeeForm").Range("D15").Value   'Last Company
    ws.Range("N" & v).Value = Worksheets("EmployeeForm").Range("D16").Value  'Join Date
    ws.Range("O" & v).Value = Worksheets("EmployeeForm").Range("D17").Value  'Position
End If

End Sub
```

The problem with your code was

```
If Cells(H) = employeeid Then
```

which is not valid syntax. Cells needs a row and column reference such cells(1,1) or cells (1,"A"). Not to mention that H wasn't defined.

Comment: Hi @SJR, thanks for your answer! It works exactly the way I want it to be! But what about if the employeeID has letters in it, like 123A in the example above? I still get the code to work, but I am concerned about the IsNumeric syntax you provided above, since 123A is not a number, right? Anyway thanks again for helping me out!

Comment: My pleasure. The `IsNumeric` bit is not checking the value of employeeid (which can be anything) but whether a match is found in column H. If employeeid is not found `v` will hold an error value and the code does not proceed.